# Jquery ajax parse html from json response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I need select a div by id from html in json response.

In server side:

```
    ob_start();

    extract($this->validate($this->data));
    require("classes/View/". $this->view . ".phtml");

    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode(array(
        'messages' => $this->data["messages"],
        'content' => $content
));
```

and in client side:

```
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: o.url ,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: o.ajax_data,
        success: function(response) {
                    $("#mydiv").html($(response.content).find("#mydiv"));
        }
    });
```

Before, when I used HTML as dataType and I returned plain HTML as response, everything have been functional.  I can't figure out the right solution even after hours of research.
Can anybody help me please?

**===UPDATE 1===**

console.log(response.content) => {"messages":[],"content":"complete escaped html site here"}

Comment: You've failed to provide the most important detail: The actual contents of the response.

Comment: I'm sure that I have in response.content loaded complete html structure of my site.

Comment: Of course my and your solution does not work -- `response.content` contains absolutely no `<div id="mydiv">` so `jquery.find()` cannot find it - it just returns empty jquery object. **Please edit your view file and insert that html div container and some text** and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing `#mydiv` (placeholder element in response) into DOM placeholder `#mydiv`.
What you are probably want to do is place content of `#mydiv` from response into placeholder.

Assuming your `response.content` is properly formed html code this should work:

```
var content = $(response.content).find("#mydiv").html(); // get html of #mydiv in response
$("#mydiv").html(content);
```

Comment: I traied your suggestion. But does not work. I need refresh part of site therefore I am placing #mydiv (placeholder element in response) into DOM placeholder #mydiv. In response.content I have a comple structure of site (<html><head></head><body>...). That is probably important key of my problem that I forgot mention. Actually console.log(content) => null